# Julia function signatures and sub-types, specifically String, ByteString

Tags: templates, types, julia, dispatch

(Using Julia 0.3.11)
I'm having trouble type-annotating correctly some of my code, in an initial version we've been using `ASCIIString` - to annotate any String, to "avoid" abstract types, but let's start with the example, this might be related to what I've seen refereed to as "triangular dispatch" in some discussions here:

```
# How to type annotate this (sortof "Dictionary with default)
function pushval!(dict, key, val)
  key in keys(dict) ? push!(dict[key], val) : dict[key] = [val]
  return dict
end

d1 = Dict{ASCIIString, Vector{Int}}()
d2 = Dict{String, Vector{Int}}()

pushval!(d1, "a", 1)
pushval!(d2, "a", 1)
```

Ok (firstly - if there's a more idiomatic way to construct a dictionary with defaults, in this case an empty array, I'd love to hear about it)

So now, I've tried to type annotated it:

```
function pushval!{K, V} (dict::Dict{K, Vector{V}} , key, val)
```

Much more documenting, and works.
But now comes the trickier part - I want 'key' to be any subtype of K, and val - any subtypes of V (right?) eg - I would like to make a dictionary of String - which is an abstract type, but use concrete keys - which are ASCIIString/ByteString/UTF8String,

I thought I should write one of the followings:

```
function pushval!{K, V} (dict::Dict{K, Vector{V}} , key::KK <: K, val:: VV <: V)
function pushval!{K, V, KK <: K, VV <: V} (dict::Dict{K, Vector{V}} , key::KK, val::VV)
```

One solution would be as suggest in ( [Can I use a subtype of a function parameter in the function definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746405/can-i-use-a-subtype-of-a-function-parameter-in-the-function-definition) ) something with 'convert'.

But this whole thing made me wonder about the Julia code I'm writing, I've started a write a system - using String, FloatingPoint, Number and such abstract types, when I actually tried running it, I've reverted to convert everything to concrete types just to get thing running for now...

Is there a recommended codebase to read as a reference to idiomatic Julia code?
Like the very implementation of Julia's dictionary-assign operator even. Is there a part of the standard library considered good to start with as a reference? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is only partly what you asked for, but maybe you find it sufficient.

What you call `pushval!` can be achieved using `push!(get!(d1, "a", []), 1)` (although it will return the dictionary value that was appended to instead of the dictionary itself). If you need to constrain the type of the inner collection's values, you can, for example, use:

```
push!(get!(d1, "a", Number[]), 1)
```

If you really need to define this as a function, I am afraid that, at the moment, you cannot define the types in the way you describe. As the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30759572/4235730) to the question you referenced notes, Julia does not implement triangular dispatch yet, although [it is targeted for 0.5](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6984#issuecomment-49751358).

Comment: That's great to know, so this is a case of 'triangular dispatch' after all. and I was not aware of get!() which is an idiom I need here! thanks!

Comment: Q: I've tried adding ' key :: K ; val :: V; ' - as type assertions on function entrance. While on the REPL - these seem to give the assertions I expect - within the function - they seem to be ignored, I had to write them as " @assert( typeof(key) <: K ) ; etc, which is what I thought " key :: K " would do, any input on that?

Comment: I have a suspicion, but I'm not sure I mean the same thing. Could you please post some more code? (Maybe you should ask this as another question?)

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't like this this solution very much (low performance), it can be helpful:

```
function pushval!{K, V} (dict::Dict{K, Vector{V}} , key , val)
  fun = function inner{tt1<:K,tt2<:V}(key::tt1,val::tt2)
   key in keys(dict) ? push!(dict[key], val) : dict[key] = [val]
   return dict
  end
  return fun(key,val)
end
# => pushval! (generic function with 1 method)
d1 = Dict{ASCIIString, Vector{Int}}()
# => Dict{ASCIIString,Array{Int32,1}} with 0 entries
d2 = Dict{String, Vector{Int}}()
# => Dict{String,Array{Int32,1}} with 0 entries

pushval!(d1, "a", 1)
# => Dict{ASCIIString,Array{Int32,1}} with 1 entry:
#    "a" => [1]

pushval!(d2, "a", 1)
# => Dict{String,Array{Int32,1}} with 1 entry:
#    "a" => [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend looking at [Julia Style Guide](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/style-guide/). There are some advices about using type annotations.

For your case you don't need type annotations for `pushval!` function at all.  Julia will get enough info from `Dict` creation and deduce appropriate types for `pushval!` arguments.

```
function pushval!(dict, key, val)
    key in keys(dict) ? push!(dict[key], val) : dict[key] = [val]
    return dict
end

d = Dict{String, Vector{Int} # Here is all annotations you need.

pushval!(d, "a", 1) # OK, "a" is ASCIIString which is subtype of AbstractString
pushval!(d, 1, 1) # ERROR, 1 is Int64 which is not subtype of AbstractString
```

Comment: I know this works, this is how it works in my production code for a few months already. The Style-Guide is a good reference, though the 'other' style guide is more to the point I think [https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/Style.jl ]. the guideline is "Don't explicitly introduce a parametric type rule for a function unless it's needed to ensure correctness". It's essential for correctness that ''dict'' is a dict->array(something), and that 'key' is a subtype of the keytype, and so on. Doing less - is under-documenting, and gives somewhat cryptic error messages if called with the wrong args.